# Implementing MIPS instructions for an absolute value function

Tags: function, assembly, mips, absolute-value

I'm really struggling in my EE class this semester and my professor goes through MIPS instructions like we're fluent in it! I've tried the book, Google, YouTube, tutoring, and talking with students, but it either doesn't make sense or they're not confident enough to help.

I really have little to no confidence in how to begin the code. I got it set up, but idk what to do. I'll provide the question and I'll update what I have as I receive help.

### Question:

> "Using only MIPS integer instructions, write a function that will make
> x = abs(y) where x and y are floating-point numbers. *Your function
> only needs to handle normal float values correctly, not NaN, etc.*"

[image]

### Attempt in the works:

(haven't made progress yet :( )

```
####
#
# Float absolute value
#
# x = abs(y)
# 

.text
.globl myabs

myabs:

    li $t0,y    #register t0 = y
#   more code..
#

    jr  $ra     # return
```

If anyone can provide some good reference material, tips, suggestions, advice, hints, or anything, I'd greatly appreciate it! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

So, ieee754.
Read about it.
Think about it.
Realize it's signed-magnitude.
On MIPS, it so happens that the sign-bit is in the same position in the word as the most significant bit in an integer.

```
load float as integer x
AND x with 0x7fffffff
store x as float
```

Comment: I just read some things about it, but it seems like there is a lot you can do with ieee 754. My question seems rather vague compared to how specific things can get. Wouldn't a 32 bit unsigned int be 6 positions? So wouldn't signed would be 7?

Comment: I have no idea what you meant by "positions". A `float` is generally 32 bit, an `int` is often (though not always) 32 bit. The `unsigned` versions of integer datatypes are the same size as the `signed` versions (which is why `unsigned`-types can represent about twice the maximum value `signed` types can).

Comment: Like that second line that you put, I don't really understand :( I'm looking at it like binary. So starting from the least significant f, I keep thinking the 7 is in the 128 position.

Comment: I looked over my notes again. Memory is generally 64 bits, so is the 7 the sign?

Comment: Pretty much all documentation on processors will explain their operation by treating any binary data as an array of bits, zero-indexed. A 32-bit datatype is composed of bits 0-31.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry. This makes no sense to me :(

Comment: Sorry. I'm not going to try to explain binary in this comment section. Go read a book on it, or browse for explanations on the net or something.

Comment: What would you recommend to search exactly? I keep doing searches, but I can't seem to search the correct queries.

Comment: @Habit: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number This should give you a starting point. Also, en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement is useful to understand.